# How to migrate bounty to normal question?

Tags: feature-request, migration, questions, bounty

I started a bounty. How can I migrate it to a normal question? Does it have a deadline for migrating?

Comment: I have no idea what a "normal question" is, or what "migrating a bounty" is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bounty lasts for a few days. If you look at the question, it'll tell you how much time is remaining. You can't take it back, but if an answer is good, you can assign the bounty. If not, just wait it out.